# Running Tomcat 9 with SpringBoot-App as a service with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, tomcat, service

actually I'm not able to run a Tomcat9-WebApp properly. I'd be thankful for any help pointing me in the right direction.

---

***Setup:***

**OS**: Ubuntu 18.04

**App-Server**: Tomcat 9.0.12 (also tested with 8.5.34)

**Web-App**: SpringBoot 1.5.7

**JDK**: 1.8.0_181

**Script-Command for the startup**: $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh

**setenv.sh**:

```
    JRE_HOME=path/to/jdk
    CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/tomcat.pid"
    LOGGING_CONFIG="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/log4j2.xml"
    LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager"

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-jul-2.11.1.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar
```

---

If I'm running the script as a root-user it works properly and the tomcat is fully functional.

But if I'm running the same script as a service it hangs during deployment of the WAR. CPU-usage raises constantly to 100%

`systemctl start tomcat`

Trace-Logs make me thinking, Tomcat is scanning each directory of the filesystem for Configuration-classes (e.g.: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:18.6/subsystem/)

`o.a.c.s.ContextConfig: Scanning directory for class files with annotations [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:18.6/subsystem ....`

The Logfiles itselfs are bigger than 200MB. The upper line is just a sample.

As said before, any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

@Edit

Progress: I reseted the tomcat-logging to default. As soon as this is done. Everything works fine.

---

Best wishes

Mike

Comment: Have you considered using an embedded Tomcat servlet instead?

Comment: No, not yet. Is this problem a known issue and gets fixed with the Tomcat-Libs?

Comment: Honestly I've never seen Tomcat scanning the entire filesystem before so I'm not sure. We are currently using Spring Boot 2 with a dependency to `spring-boot-starter-web` (which includes Tomcat) and the context initializes in about 20 seconds even for very large applications - are there any `@ComponentScan`, `@ImportResource` or similar annotations on your project which may be misconfigured?

Comment: I also haven't seen this behavior before. I don't think there is a misconfiguration inside the app. The application is finely deployed and started if I run the same script as as root-user. I think there is a context-change while running as service.

Comment: Have you tried backing up first, and then modifying the systemd tomcat config file?  You can try and have it run as the tomcat user with group tomcat  which you would need to add first.  If you need an example I can provide it for you.  Not sure though if you'll run into the same problem but possibly worth a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working:

The issue depends on the export CLASSPATH-Command:

I don't know why, but there must not be the extension of the CLASSPATH.

Solution:
Replace

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-jul-2.11.1.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar
```

with

```
export CLASSPATH=$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-jul-2.11.1.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar
```

and the service is starting properly.

If anyone could give an explanation to this behavior. Me and I'll bet others too would love get deeper into this.

---

@Edit

Well I have a possible explanation for this behavior. As $CLASSPATH is not defined during startup the result is possible "". So the starting of this line seems to be "**:**/another/path..." It could interepreted like "**/:**/another/path...". The result is, that "/" is member of the classpath. That could force spring to scan the whole filesystem.

Important: This is only a guess and it is not verified.